# How to assign label value from an Action in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to set a label value using an Action which returns a string (basically, i want the company name to appear in the footer of my website).

For this, i have done the following.

in the view

```
    <label>@Url.Action("GetCompanyName", "Home")</label>
```

and in the controller

```
    public ActionResult GetCompanyName()
    {
       return Content("CompanyName");
    }
```

and the output is follows

```
    /Home/GetCompanyName
```

I know this is not right way to do it..

Can any one help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
 <label>@{Html.RenderAction("GetCompanyName", "Home");}</label>
```

What you were doing, was getting the route to your view, what this does, is renders the result inline on your page.

- **Url.Action** - Generates a fully qualified URL to an action method
- **Html.RenderAction** - Invokes the specified child action method and
  renders the result inline in the parent view
- **Html.Action** - Invokes the specified child action method with the
  specified parameters and returns the result as an HTML string.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I found we can do it by @Html.action too.. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: As per my requirement, i found the best way is 

@Html.Action("GetCompanyName", "Home").